# Borders only showing on the sides in html

Tags: html, css

When I am trying to add a border to a div element on my website, I am getting these weird borders.

[image: Weird CSS Borders]

This is the result I was looking for:
[intended result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7pMdU.png)

**HTML**

```
<div>
<h1 class="headline">hey</h1>
<div class="buttons">
<a class="filled-button"><p class="filled-button-text">sign up</p></a>
<a class="outlined-button"><p class="outlined-button-text">log in</p></a>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outlined-button
{
 border: 3px solid #fff;
 border-radius: 10px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 height: 48px;
 width: 140px;
}
.outlined-button-text
{
 color: #fff;
 font-family: Roboto;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 24px;
 line-height: 28px;
}
```

Comment: I should mention i'm using the latest version of firefox developer edition (70.0b9)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! That could be anything under the sun, pleasse post a minimal working example as detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. could be using codepen or jsfiddle or even the built in editor.

Comment: plz show your mark up also

Comment: Does the thing that has the border happen to be displayed inline? If so, try adding `display: inline-block`.

Comment: hi, i've put it all under this jsfiddle, thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/jsp3uemL/

Comment: `text-align: center` missing a `;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of the border is that `a` elements have inline flow while the enclosed `p` element has `display block` behaviour. Inline elements have no inherited width, this causes the border property to think that the element is 0 px wide, and places a border where it thinks the element is.

A fix for your solution is to use `display: block` for the link element(https://jsfiddle.net/qtdz296j/1/)

I also attached an alternative solution:

```css
body {
    background: #162CEA;
    padding: 2rem 1rem;
}

.heading {
  color: #FFF;
}

.button {
  padding: .5rem 1rem;
  border-radius: .5rem;
}

.filled-button {
  background: #FFF;
}

.outline-button {
  border: 3px solid #FFF;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="heading">hey<h1>

<a class="button filled-button">sign up</a>
<a class="button outline-button">log in</a>
```

Comment: I would recommend `display: inline-block` instead of `display: block`.  This allows the button to stay in the inline flow, like a regular button would.

Answer (score 1):

Can't tell anything without the rest of the css and html.  Your post starts in the middle of a rule.  I'd try playing with it and see what you can change.  Make sure your css is affecting the elements you want it to be affecting.

Edit: Try changing your `<p>` tags inside the buttons to `<span>`.  Or better yet, don't enclose them in anything, and just style the button text directly.  I also highly suggest looking into the correct use of `<button>` vs. `<a>`.  It's a lot easier to make buttons work when they're actually *buttons*.  But changing the `<p>`s to an inline element like `<span>` will fix your immediate problem.

Comment: hi, here's a jsfiddle of my code, https://jsfiddle.net/jsp3uemL/

Comment: @BenClark to whic `<div>` do you want to add the border styling to the `<div>` with the `class=''buttons"` or just to the `<a>` tag?

Comment: Just to the <a> tag with the class outlined-button

Comment: It's happening because of the <p> tags inside your buttons.  Updated my answer above.

Comment: @BenClark is this what you're looking for? [Code sample](https://jsfiddle.net/839yogbn/)

Answer (score 0):

this works if you just need a  border around that div. cleaned it up a little and added a missing `;`. it there are a lot of nested classes and you just need to target the right one. there are only 2 divs in this, so if you are talking about the outer/parent div, just give that an id and target it. Enjoy!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='styles.css'>
    <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>

    <script>
      // Your web app's Firebase configuration
      var firebaseConfig = {
      };
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h1 class="headline">hey</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a class="filled-button"><p class="filled-button-text">sign up</p></a>
            <a class="outlined-button"><p class="outlined-button-text">log in</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<style>
body {
    background: #162CEA;
}
.headline {
    width: 34%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 64px;
    line-height: 75px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.filled-button-text {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.filled-button {
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    height: 48px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #000000;
    display: table;
    text-align: center;
}
.outlined-button {
    width: 140px;
    height: 48px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.outlined-button-text {
    font-family: Roboto;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 24px;
    line-height: 28px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.buttons {
    border: 2px solid black;
}
</style>
</html>
```

Comment: hi, this appears to have just added a border around both buttons, (i've updated the post to show the result i was looking for) Thanks!

Comment: oh, you asked the wrong question then, there are only 2 divs and that button isn't one of them. Using IDs might be of help in the future. just name the id in the html parameters and call it in the css. cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code

```css
body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            font-family: Roboto;
            background-color: #162cea;
        } 
        .headline {
            text-align: center;
            color: #ffffff;
        }
        .buttons {
            padding: 30px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            text-align: center;
        }
        .filled-button {
            border-radius: 10px;
            color: #000000;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 30px;
            height: 55px;
            width: 140px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
            display: inline-block;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 0 10px 0 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .filled-button .filled-button-text {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 9px;
        }
        .outlined-button {
            border-radius: 10px;
            color: #ffffff;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: 30px;
            height: 52px;
            width: 140px;
            background-color: #162cea;
            display: inline-block;
            border: 3px solid #ffffff;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 0 0 0 10px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .outlined-button .outlined-button-text {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 9px;
        }
```

```html
<div>
        <h1 class="headline">hey</h1>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a class="filled-button"><p class="filled-button-text">sign up</p></a>
            <a class="outlined-button"><p class="outlined-button-text">log in</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Hello I hope this will help. and a small advice, as you might already know it. do not use a block level element inside a inline element even though you are changing the display property its safer that way.
```

```css
body {
  background: #162CEA;
}

.headline {
  width: 34%;
  margin-top: 15%;
  margin-left: 15%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 64px;
  line-height: 75px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.button {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.filled-button-text,
.outlined-button-text {
  display: block;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 1.75em;
  line-height: 2.25em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.outlined-button-text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.filled-button {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.filled-button,
.outlined-button {
  width: 49%;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #FFFFFF;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
  <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='styles.css'>
  <!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.0.0/firebase-auth.js"></script>

  <script>
    // Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {};
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <h1 class="headline">hey</h1>
    <div class="buttons">
      <a class="filled-button">
        <span class="filled-button-text">sign up</span>
      </a>
      <a class="outlined-button">
        <span class="outlined-button-text">log in</span>
      </a>


    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```